# Redis vs MongoDB with expiration for storing async results

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, redis

I need to introduce asynchronous processing to a system: when a request comes I start a background job and respond with an url to poll for results later. The processing itself shouldn't take more than a few minutes, and the results should be kept in storage for around a half hour. Replaying the processing can be expensive, so the chances of loosing the results due to a storage outage should be reduced.

I'm evaluating the advantages of Redis and Mongo (using a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)) to store the results.

The system already uses both, so there isn't an extra cost for introducing a new technology in either case. In case of going with Redis, I understand I'd have to set it up to use [AOF persistence](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html) to reduce the chance of data loss, which would imply a bit of a performance penalty for other Redis use cases (such as caching).

I'm more interested in data integrity than performance. I understand both options should work well, I wonder if one is better suited for this particular use case or one is more prone to buy me operational problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Redis will be better choice over MongoDB in your case. Above situation is similar to the leader board which maintains the result till its expiry time. A cache layer can probably be better implemented in Redis, and as for a more schema-able data MongoDB might be better.

You need the caching for storing the result for the processed job.